# xcode 5 file navigation for visual studio user

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, navigation

I've used Visual Studio for years and have just started work on a C++ project in XCode, and I'm finding some aspects of file navigation in XCode frustrating.

If I have several files open, and I use the mouse swipe left or right to reveal a previous/next file, the editor always repositions the window to the top of the file, instead of where I was looking at it previously. Is there any way to keep the file positioned at previous line?

In Visual Studio I often used bookmarks within a file, and then keyboard shortcuts to move forwards and backwards through them. Is there an equivalent in XCode?

Is there any shortcut to show a list of the currently open files so that I can view one of them? (I miss the Visual Studio tabs.)

Comment: I found that you can click & hold on the left/right navigation arrows in the bar above the file window and it will give you a popup list of the currently open windows, so that you can then select the required file.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same complaints and have not found a good solution, but there are a couple of things I have done.
I have placed commented out keywords throughout my code. For example, when I was implementing iAds into my project I added "//iads imp" into my code, thus I was able to quickly do a command+f and type in "iads imp" and I would go to that section of code.

The other solution I use for this is pragma marks:

[According to this site](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2006/09/tip-pragma-mark-organizing-your-source.html),
"Pragma mark is simply a way to organize your methods in the method list pop up button in Xcode "